# how to show a option value for select field in magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer-attribute, checkout-page

sample code

```
$opt_val = array();
foreach ($attributeOptionAll->getData() as $key => $v) {
    $opt_val['value']=$v['option_id'];
    $opt_val['label'] = $v['value'];
var_dump($opt_val);

}
```

output:
[image]

> app/code/Cm/CustomerAttribute/Model/Plugin/Checkout/Lauoutprocessor.php

```
<?php
namespace Cm\CustomerAttribute\Model\Plugin\Checkout;

class LayoutProcessor
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
     public function __construct(\Cm\CustomerAttribute\Helper\Customerattribute $helper)
    {
        $this->helper = $helper;
    }

    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array  $jsLayout
    ) {

 $attributeCollection = $this->helper->getUserDefinedAttribures();

    if ($attributeCollection->getSize() > 0) 
    {
         foreach ($attributeCollection as $attribute)

       {
        if ($this->helper->isAttribureForCheckoutRegister($attribute->getAttributeCode()))
        {
        $frontEndLabel = $attribute->getStoreLabel($this->helper->getStoreId());
        $attributeCode = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
        $getAttributeCodeFunction = "get" .  str_replace(' ', '', ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $attribute->getAttributeCode())));
        $fieldRequiredClass = ($attribute->getIsRequired()) ? 'true' : '' ;
        $fieldFrontendClass = ($attribute->getFrontendClass()) ? $attribute->getFrontendClass() : '';
        $fieldInput =$attribute->getFrontendInput();
        if($fieldInput == 'text')
        {
            $fieldInputType = 'input';
            $fieldAbstract =  'abstract';
        }
        elseif ($fieldInput == 'date') {
           $fieldInputType = 'date'; 
           $fieldAbstract =  'abstract';
        }
        elseif ($fieldInput == 'select') {
           $fieldInputType = 'select'; 
           $fieldAbstract =  'select';
        }
        elseif ($fieldInput == 'multiselect') {
           $fieldInputType = 'multiselect'; 
           $fieldAbstract =  'abstract';

        }
        elseif ($fieldInput == 'boolean') {
           $fieldInputType = 'boolean'; 
           $fieldAbstract =  'abstract';

        }
         elseif ($fieldInput == 'textarea') {
           $fieldInputType = 'textarea'; 
           $fieldAbstract =  'abstract';

        }
        $attributeId = $attribute->getAttributeId();
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

        $attributeOptionAll = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Option\Collection::class)
                                    ->setPositionOrder('asc')
                                    ->setAttributeFilter($attributeId)
                                    ->setStoreFilter()
                                    ->load();
        $opt_val = array();
        $opt_label  = array();
        foreach ($attributeOptionAll->getData() as $key => $v) 
        {
          $opt_val['value']=$v['option_id'];
          $opt_val['label'] = $v['value'];

        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children'][$attributeCode] = [
            'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/'.$fieldAbstract.'',
            'config' => [
                'customScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes',
                'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/'.$fieldInputType.'',
                'id' => $attributeCode
            ],
            'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes.'.$attributeCode.'',
            'label' => $frontEndLabel,
            'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
            'visible' => true,
            'validation' =>[$fieldFrontendClass , 
                'required-entry' => $fieldRequiredClass],
            'sortOrder' => 250,
             'options' =>  [$opt_val],  
            'id' => $attributeCode
        ];
         }
        }
       }
     }
     return $jsLayout;  
    }
}
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are not getting all your options in dropdown is because you are creating your component in `foreach`. It will always give you the last option in your component.
You can update your code like below.

```
$opt_val = array();
$opt_label  = array();
$allOptions = [];
foreach ($attributeOptionAll->getData() as $key => $v) 
{
    $opt_val['value']=$v['option_id'];
    $opt_val['label'] = $v['value'];
    $allOptions[] = $opt_val;
}

$jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children'][$attributeCode] = [
'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/'.$fieldAbstract.'',
'config' => [
    'customScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes',
    'template' => 'ui/form/field',
    'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/'.$fieldInputType.'',
    'id' => $attributeCode
],
'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes.'.$attributeCode.'',
'label' => $frontEndLabel,
'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
'visible' => true,
'validation' =>[$fieldFrontendClass , 
    'required-entry' => $fieldRequiredClass],
'sortOrder' => 250,
 'options' =>  $allOptions,  
'id' => $attributeCode
];
```

Comment: Glad to thanks for your help its works https://prnt.sc/od3ilb